# PHP array for raffles

Tags: php, arrays

**I'm trying to make a [raffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raffle) system**

- The total of possible numbers are 60,000
- I'm selling 10,000 tickets
- There are 50,000 non used tickets that I have to use... so each ticket have a extra "opportunities" to win. 50,000 non selling tickets divided by 10,000 selling tickets
- Each ticket gets 5 extra opportunities.

Knowing this, what I need is something like this:

**Ticket: Opport1,Opport2,Opport3,Opport4,Opport5**

```
00001: ["20000","20001","40000","40001","60000"] 
00002: ["19999","20002","39999","40002","59999"]
00003: ["19998","20003","39998","40003","59998"] 
00004: ["19997","20004","39997","40004","59997"] 
00005: ["19996","20005","39996","40005","59996"]
.
.
.
09995: ["10006","29995","30006","49995","50006"]
09996: ["10005","29996","30005","49996","50005"]
09997: ["10004","29997","30004","49997","50004"]
09998: ["10003","29998","30003","49998","50003"]
09999: ["10002","29999","30002","49999","50002"]
10000: ["10001","30000","30001","50000","50001"]
```

Because I cant use the already 10,000 selling tickets.

The first column start in 20,000 and descending to 10,001
Second column start in 20,001 and end in 30,000 and so on.

I already have this code and it works like this.

```
function randomGen($min, $max, $quantity) {
        $numbers = range($min, $max);
        $find = array("[","]");
        $replace = array("","");
        $cadena = str_replace($find, $replace, json_encode(array_slice($numbers, 0, $quantity)));
        return $cadena;
    }

    $minCol1 = 20000;
    $maxCol1 = 10001;

    $minCol2 = 20001;
    $maxCol2 = 30000;

    $minCol3 = 40000;
    $maxCol3 = 30001;

    $minCol4 = 40001;
    $maxCol4 = 50000;

    $minCol5 = 60000;
    $maxCol5 = 50001;
    for($i = 1; $i<=10000; $i++){
        $oportunidades = randomGen($minCol1,$maxCol1,1).",".randomGen($minCol2,$maxCol2,1).",".randomGen($minCol3,$maxCol3,1).",".randomGen($minCol4,$maxCol4,1).",".randomGen($minCol5,$maxCol5,1);
        $str_arr = explode (",", $oportunidades);
        ?>
        <li>
            <span data-oportunidades='<? echo(json_encode($str_arr));?>'>
                <?=str_pad($i, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);?>
            </span>
        </li>
    <?
        $minCol1 = $minCol1 -1;
        $maxCol1 = $minCol1 -1;

        $minCol2 = $minCol2 +1;
        $maxCol2 = $minCol2 +1;

        $minCol3 = $minCol3 -1;
        $maxCol3 = $minCol3 -1;

        $minCol4 = $minCol4 +1;
        $maxCol4 = $minCol4 +1;

        $minCol5 = $minCol5 -1;
        $maxCol5 = $minCol5 -1;
    }
```

But im pretty sure this is NOT the right way to solve this.

Someone have any idea how to do this?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Looks like something that could be reviewed on [codereview.se].

Comment: Perhaps for the lazy under us: PHP has `array_chunk()`. Just an idea, if doing the math within memory is easier than modulo etc. operations. -- And pro-tip: If it works you have proven it's the _right_ way, this is the main test. There are always _many ways to shave a yak_, but this is the main test you want first of all. You should [edit] the question and share if it works first of all and then for which part you're looking for improvements, e.g. what does not feel right for you with the code or what you want to get rid of. This will give you better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want something like this:

```php
// This is an example function to generate initial tickets
function genTickets(int $num): array
{
    $tickets = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
        $tickets[] = $i + 1;
    }

    return $tickets;
}

function getTicketsSlice(array $tickets, bool $ascending, int $count, int $offset): array
{
    $slice = array_slice($tickets, $offset, $count);

    if (!$ascending) {
        return array_reverse($slice);
    }

    return $slice;
}

function getSoldTicketsWithOpportunities(array $tickets, int $soldTicketsCnt): array
{
    $opportunities = (int)floor((count($tickets) - $soldTicketsCnt) / $soldTicketsCnt);

    $soldTickets = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i < $opportunities; $i++) {
        $ascending = $i % 2 !== 0;

        foreach (getTicketsSlice($tickets, $ascending, $soldTicketsCnt, ($i + 1) * $soldTicketsCnt) as $idx => $sliceItem) {
            $soldTickets[$idx][] = $sliceItem;
        }
    }

    return $soldTickets;
}

$totalTicketsCnt = 60000;
$soldTicketsCnt = 10000;

$tickets = genTickets($totalTicketsCnt);
$soldTickets = getSoldTicketsWithOpportunities($tickets, $soldTicketsCnt);

foreach ($soldTickets as $ticketId => $opportunities) {
    ?>
    <li>
        <span data-oportunidades='<?= json_encode($opportunities, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR) ?>'>
            <?= str_pad((string)($ticketId + 1), 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) ?>
        </span>
    </li>
    <?php
}
```

Or in less automatic way:

```php
// This is an example function to generate initial tickets
function genTickets(int $num): array
{
    $tickets = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
        $tickets[] = $i + 1;
    }

    return $tickets;
}

function getTicketsSlice(array $tickets, bool $ascending, int $count, int $offset): array
{
    $slice = array_slice($tickets, $offset, $count);

    if (!$ascending) {
        return array_reverse($slice);
    }

    return $slice;
}

$totalTicketsCnt = 60000;
$soldTicketsCnt = 10000;

$tickets = genTickets($totalTicketsCnt);

// Get tickets slice from 10000 to 20000 in reverse order
foreach (getTicketsSlice($tickets, false, $soldTicketsCnt, 10000) as $sliceItem) {
    $soldTickets[] = [$sliceItem];
}

// Apply next opportunities in ascending order
foreach (getTicketsSlice($tickets, true, $soldTicketsCnt, 20000) as $idx => $sliceItem) {
    $soldTickets[$idx][] = $sliceItem;
}

// Apply next opportunities in descending order
foreach (getTicketsSlice($tickets, false, $soldTicketsCnt, 30000) as $idx => $sliceItem) {
    $soldTickets[$idx][] = $sliceItem;
}

// Apply next opportunities in ascending order
foreach (getTicketsSlice($tickets, true, $soldTicketsCnt, 40000) as $idx => $sliceItem) {
    $soldTickets[$idx][] = $sliceItem;
}

// Apply next opportunities in descending order
foreach (getTicketsSlice($tickets, false, $soldTicketsCnt, 50000) as $idx => $sliceItem) {
    $soldTickets[$idx][] = $sliceItem;
}

foreach ($soldTickets as $ticketId => $opportunities) {
    ?>
    <li>
        <span data-oportunidades='<?= json_encode($opportunities, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR) ?>'>
            <?= str_pad((string)($ticketId + 1), 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) ?>
        </span>
    </li>
    <?php
}
```